# Copy reference instead of value/formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I have some cells from one table I which I want to reproduce in another table, initially in the same order (but later, I'll mess this order up by moving cells around). For the sake of discussion suppose it's an arbitrary subset of cells, and that these cells contain an immediate value, not a formula. So, I'll just select these cells and copy them, right? Well, ok, but suppose I occasionally update cells in the original table, and I want the copies to be updated as well.

What I would like to be able to do is when I copy the selection of cells to be able to paste references to the original cells rather the immediate values. Is something like that possible?

**Notes:**

- If it makes it easier to answer, you may assume it is a short row or column vector of cells that I want copied.
- I don't care about cell formatting.
- It's too many cells to just make the references manually, I want to copy-paste them.

Comment: You want to copy specific cells' references and paste them in a different order maintaining the references?

Comment: @Raystafarian: Not exactly, will clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Copy -> Paste Special -> Paste Link
```

and note that this creates an absolute reference (e.g. $A$1).